# Multiple filter conditions in Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, lodash

I have an Array of Objects containing product information where there are categories and colors as fields. Now, I have another array containing which categories and which colors to show.

Main Array:

```
products: [{
id: 1,
  name: 'Product 1',
  category: 'Home',
  skill: 'Easy',
  color: 'blue',
  price: 100.00
}, {
    id: 2,
  name: 'Product 2',
  category: 'Home',
  skill: 'Intermediate',
  color: 'red',
  price: 120.00
}, {
    id: 3,
  name: 'Product 3',
  category: 'Office',
  skill: 'Intermediate',
  color: 'green',
  price: 190.00
}, {
    id: 4,
  name: 'Product 4',
  category: 'Office',
  skill: 'Advanced',
  color: 'blue',
  price: 260.00
}, {
    id: 5,
  name: 'Product 5',
  category: 'Warehouse',
  skill: 'Advanced',
  color: 'white',
  price: 321.00
}, {
    id: 6,
  name: 'Product 6',
  category: 'Farm',
  skill: 'Intermediate',
  color: 'red',
  price: 120.00
}, {
    id: 7,
  name: 'Product 7',
  category: 'Space',
  skill: 'Advanced',
  color: 'green',
  price: 150.00
}, {
    id: 8,
  name: 'Product 8',
  category: 'Bathroom',
  skill: 'Easy',
  color: 'black',
  price: 9.00
}],
```

My another array containing filter options:

```
selectedFilters: {
 categories : ["home", "bathroom"] ,
 colors : ["blue", "red"] 
}
```

Now I want my output as:

```
[{
id: 1,
  name: 'Product 1',
  category: 'Home',
  skill: 'Easy',
  color: 'blue',
  price: 100.00
}, {
    id: 2,
  name: 'Product 2',
  category: 'Home',
  skill: 'Intermediate',
  color: 'red',
  price: 120.00
}]
```

I tried the normal array filter method:

```
this.filteredProducts = this.products.filter(prod => {
  // [prod.category, prod.color].some(val => this.selectedFilters.includes(val))
  console.log(this.selectedFilters);
  for (let i = 0; i < this.selectedFilters.length; i++) {
    // console.log('Selected Category : ', this.selectedFilters[i]);
    // console.log('Product Category : ', prod.category);
    if (prod.category == this.selectedFilters[i]) {
      console.log('Called category');
      return true;
    } else if (prod.color == this.selectedFilters[i]) {
      console.log('Called color');
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log('Called else');
      continue;
    }
  }

});
```

How can I achieve this using array filter functions or Lodash functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for a library, use the standard `.filter` method to filter an array, check to see if each object's color and category is included in the selectedFilters object:

```js
const products = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Product 1',
  category: 'Home',
  skill: 'Easy',
  color: 'blue',
  price: 100.00
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Product 2',
  category: 'Home',
  skill: 'Intermediate',
  color: 'red',
  price: 120.00
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'Product 3',
  category: 'Office',
  skill: 'Intermediate',
  color: 'green',
  price: 190.00
}, {
  id: 4,
  name: 'Product 4',
  category: 'Office',
  skill: 'Advanced',
  color: 'blue',
  price: 260.00
}, {
  id: 5,
  name: 'Product 5',
  category: 'Warehouse',
  skill: 'Advanced',
  color: 'white',
  price: 321.00
}, {
  id: 6,
  name: 'Product 6',
  category: 'Farm',
  skill: 'Intermediate',
  color: 'red',
  price: 120.00
}, {
  id: 7,
  name: 'Product 7',
  category: 'Space',
  skill: 'Advanced',
  color: 'green',
  price: 150.00
}, {
  id: 8,
  name: 'Product 8',
  category: 'Bathroom',
  skill: 'Easy',
  color: 'black',
  price: 9.00
}];
const selectedFilters = {
 categories : ["home", "bathroom"] ,
 colors : ["blue", "red"] 
};

const { categories, colors } = selectedFilters;
const filteredProducts = products.filter(({ category, color }) => (
  categories.includes(category.toLowerCase()) && colors.includes(color.toLowerCase())
));
console.log(filteredProducts);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this is not working properly. I'm using this code in VueJS. Can you please help me with this? Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fsaiyed/h1gf11zn/2/)

Comment: Your colors selection is broken; it will either select all of them or select none of them. Your `selectedFilters` object is also broken - it gets assigned `false`, so of course `{ categories, colors }` cannot be destructured from it. Your new question has nothing to do with your old question.

Comment: This only works if there are values present in both of the selectedFilters categories and colors. It breaks when either selectedFilters.colors is empty or selectedFilters.categories is empty. When any one of them is empty, it should return data filtered through any one of the selectedFilter value.

Comment: What I patched is : `this.filteredProducts = this.products.filter(({ category, color }) => {
       if(categories.length > 0 && colors.length > 0){
         return categories.includes(category) && colors.includes(color)
       } else if(categories.length > 0 && colors.length == 0){
        return categories.includes(category)
       } else if(categories.length == 0 && colors.length > 0){
        return colors.includes(category)
       } else {
        return categories.includes(category) || colors.includes(color)
       }
      });`